# How can i use php-cgi.exe

Tags: php, apache

I was looking around my xampp configuration and i noticed that there's a special alias for php-cgi.exe

When i tried to access that link ( localhost/php-cgi/php-cgi.exe ) i get the following result http://prntscr.com/26exwm

```
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message: 
Premature end of script headers: php-cgi.exe

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500

localhost
11/24/13 16:02:12
Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
```

Looking around for this error, i saw only articles covering the cgi implementation of php.

What's the use of that url, and how it can be used ?

Comment: check your error logs, check what the HTML response 500 means.. Y'know, basic research

Comment: Thanks. Seems that it won't do anything if accessed directly.